# Creating a Python module in the namespace of an external library (custom spaCy language)

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, spacy

This question is in the context of adding a language to the [spaCy v2 library](https://v2.spacy.io/), but it may be a generic python packaging question.

In spaCy, languages are subclasses of a `Language` base class, and much of the tooling expects a given language to be placed in a normatively named package (e.g. `spacy.lang.en` for english).

There are various ways arount this requirement (for example, `@spacy.registry.languages`), but this usually entails a few tradeoffs (e.g. you have to import some code first to register your classes and then it's all fine, but when you have tooling like custom scripts, `prodigy` recipes, libraries, ... that do not allow you to "inject" custom imports or have their own way of doing so, this does not work - or is generally error prone). I'd be happy to hear about suggestions for easing this out if there is a way.

So I thought I'd just put my language where spaCy expects it, and I'd be fine. Creating a language subclass is [documented enough](https://v2.spacy.io/usage/adding-languages).

So I bootstraped a library :

```
lib/
  src/
    spacy/
      lang/
        ka/ # example of a language that spaCy does not know about
          __init.py__ # my language subclass
  setup.py
```

With init.py being a simple language (simplified):

```
import spacy
from spacy.language import Language


class GeorgianDefaults(Language.Defaults):

@spacy.registry.languages("ka")
class Georgian(Language):
    lang = "ka"
    Defaults = GeorgianDefaults
```

And my setup.py being a standard one, using native namespace packages:

```
setup(
    name="my-spacy-extras",
    packages=find_namespace_packages(where="src"),
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    install_requires=[
        "spacy>=2.3.0,<3.0.0"
    ]
)
```

I thought of using native namespace packages because as I understand it, this is the modern way to go for this use case.

But when I package the code (or really just setup a virtualenv and `pip install -Ur requirements.txt` with requirements being a simple `-e .`), I get the dreaded

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.lang.ka'
```

I *think* this is because spaCy itself (see the [repo](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/tree/v2.x)) does not use native namespace packging, but as it does not either use pkgutil-style packages, I'm starting to wonder if this can work at all.

So, do I have a way to create my custom language as a module, package it in a library, inside the spacy namespace (for lack of a better word) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to follow the v2 docs for spaCy v2 since there are a number of differences. (The registry decorators are new in v3).

spaCy v2 supports entry points for custom languages: https://v2.spacy.io/usage/saving-loading#entry-points

Your package will have its own name (not `spacy`) and you can add a custom language in spaCy v2 by adding an entry point under `spacy_languages` in `setup.py`:

```py
    entry_points={
        "spacy_languages": [
            "ka = spacy_lang_ka:Georgian",
        ]
    }
```

If this package is installed in your environment, then `spacy.blank("ka")` should find and load this class as `Georgian()` without any extra steps required. Likewise, prodigy should be able to load a blank language pipeline as `blank:ka`.

An example of what this looks like in a complete `setup.py` is shown in `spacy-stanza` v0.2.5:

https://github.com/explosion/spacy-stanza/blob/v0.2.5/setup.py

Comment: This is a very nice answer for my particular issue. I'd mark the answer as accepted, but I would like to see if someone has an opinion / idea that uses the packaging side of things, which is complementary to your solution.

Comment: Check that `find_namespace_packages` is returning the right output for your package structure. Try just `["spacy.lang.ka"]` instead, or limit it with `include=["spacy.lang.*"]`. In any case, the entry points are the recommended/tested approach.